# Convert this JSON data into TREE view

Tags: jquery, html

This is my `JSON` data

```
{
    "TEST": [{
        "Name": "gm:check-GetMap-request",
        "Result": "Passed",
        "ObjectID": 1,
        "ParentID": 0,
        "Indent": 1
    }, {
        "Name": "basic:mandatory-params",
        "Result": "Passed",
        "ObjectID": 2,
        "ParentID": 1,
        "Indent": 2
    }, {
        "Name": "basic:version",
        "Result": "Passed",
        "ObjectID": 3,
        "ParentID": 1,
        "Indent": 2
    }, {
        "Name": "basic:request",
        "Result": "Passed",
        "ObjectID": 4,
        "ParentID": 1,
        "Indent": 2
    }, {
        "Name": "gm:core-map-request",
        "Result": "Passed",
        "ObjectID": 5,
        "ParentID": 1,
        "Indent": 2
    }, {
        "Name": "gm:layers-count",
        "Result": "Passed",
        "ObjectID": 6,
        "ParentID": 5,
        "Indent": 3
    }, {
        "Name": "gm:layers-names",
        "Result": "Passed",
        "ObjectID": 7,
        "ParentID": 5,
        "Indent": 3
    }, {
        "Name": "gm:styles-count",
        "Result": "Passed",
        "ObjectID": 8,
        "ParentID": 5,
        "Indent": 3
    }, {
        "Name": "gm:styles-names",
        "Result": "Passed",
        "ObjectID": 9,
        "ParentID": 5,
        "Indent": 3
    }, {
        "Name": "gm:crs",
        "Result": "Passed",
        "ObjectID": 10,
        "ParentID": 5,
        "Indent": 3
    }, {
        "Name": "gm:bbox-format",
        "Result": "Passed",
        "ObjectID": 11,
        "ParentID": 5,
        "Indent": 3
    }, {
        "Name": "gm:bbox-non-subsettable-layers",
        "Result": "Passed",
        "ObjectID": 12,
        "ParentID": 5,
        "Indent": 3
    }, {
        "Name": "gm:format",
        "Result": "Passed",
        "ObjectID": 13,
        "ParentID": 5,
        "Indent": 3
    }, {
        "Name": "gm:width-height",
        "Result": "Passed",
        "ObjectID": 14,
        "ParentID": 5,
        "Indent": 3
    }, {
        "Name": "gm:width-height",
        "Result": "Passed",
        "ObjectID": 15,
        "ParentID": 5,
        "Indent": 3
    }, {
        "Name": "gm:transparent",
        "Result": "Passed",
        "ObjectID": 16,
        "ParentID": 5,
        "Indent": 3
    }]
}
```

I did not understand how to do. I want to do this using jquery.

Comment: try online tools like http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/online-json-tree-viewer, http://www.jsontree.com

Comment: https://github.com/Erffun/JsonTree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think this is what you are looking for?
and there are many plugins that can do it for you. www.jstree.com being one of many.

```
var data = [
    {
        "text": "Chocolate Beverage",
        "id": "1",
        "parentid": "-1"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "parentid": "1",
        "text": "Hot Chocolate"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "parentid": "1",
        "text": "Peppermint Hot Chocolate"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "parentid": "1",
        "text": "Salted Caramel Hot Chocolate"
    }, {
        "id": "5",
        "parentid": "1",
        "text": "White Hot Chocolate"
    }, {
        "id": "6",
        "text": "Espresso Beverage",
        "parentid": "-1"
    }, {
        "id": "7",
        "parentid": "6",
        "text": "Caffe Americano"
    }, {
        "id": "8",
        "text": "Caffe Latte",
        "parentid": "6"
    }, {
        "id": "9",
        "text": "Caffe Mocha",
        "parentid": "6"
    }, {
        "id": "10",
        "text": "Cappuccino",
        "parentid": "6"
    }, {
        "id": "11",
        "text": "Pumpkin Spice Latte",
        "parentid": "6"
    }, {
        "id": "12",
        "text": "Frappuccino",
        "parentid": "-1"
    }, {
        "id": "13",
        "text": "Caffe Vanilla Frappuccino",
        "parentid": "12"
    }, {
        "id": "15",
        "text": "450 calories",
        "parentid": "13"
    }, {
        "id": "16",
        "text": "16g fat",
        "parentid": "13"
    }, {
        "id": "17",
        "text": "13g protein",
        "parentid": "13"
    }, {
        "id": "14",
        "text": "Caffe Vanilla Frappuccino Light",
        "parentid": "12"
    }]
```

We will iterate through the data and build our hierarchical data source that we will pass to the Tree plugin. Here’s the to code for the builddata function.

```
var builddata = function () {
    var source = [];
    var items = [];
    // build hierarchical source.
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var item = data[i];
        var label = item["text"];
        var parentid = item["parentid"];
        var id = item["id"];

        if (items[parentid]) {
            var item = { parentid: parentid, label: label, item: item };
            if (!items[parentid].items) {
                items[parentid].items = [];
            }
            items[parentid].items[items[parentid].items.length] = item;
            items[id] = item;
        }
        else {
            items[id] = { parentid: parentid, label: label, item: item };
            source[id] = items[id];
        }
    }
    return source;
}
```

After calling the builddata function, we will have a data source which is readable by the Tree. Let’s create the Tree plugin and populate it with data. To add the jqxTree to your page, you should include the javascript files and css stylesheets. You can take a look at the list of dependencies here: jquery-tree-getting-started The next step is to add a DIV element to the document’s body.

```
<div id='jqxTree'>
</div>
```

Finally, call the builddata function and create the jqxTree.

```
var source = builddata();
// create jqxTree
$('#jqxTree').jqxTree({ source: source, width: '350px' });
```